# How to find directory in realtion to Pycharm project root?

Tags: python, path, pycharm

I simply created a new project in Pycharm, and added directory *cfg* to it. I simply want to check in my *main.py* if in fact, my *cfg* directory is where it supposed to be, just want to check if hierarhy of my projest from within python (i wrote in pycharm, but it may be my code will be exported somewhere else and I want to make sure my paths wont be affected). I expected Pycharm to add some environment variable that i can use as project root, but found nothing. Can you tell me, what best practices are in such cases?
Next step will be to check if config yaml/json file is inside such directory.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use the `os.path.isdir()` function.
This function takes a path as input, and returns True if the path is a directory, returns False if it is not. Here is code you can use to check if the `cfg` directory is in the project root:

```
import os

def is_cfg_directory_in_project_root():
    """Check if the `cfg` directory is in the project 
root."""
    cfg_directory = 
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "cfg")
    return os.path.isdir(cfg_directory)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(is_cfg_directory_in_project_root())
```

Comment: Close to what I am looking, but `__file__` gives us path of current file, so relative path will be from this file to `cfg` directory, not main root directory. If i am correct ofc. As for now, I am unsure where in project tree this file will be.

Comment: I was thinking about setting some environment variable indicationg my main project directory, but i thought pyCharm already adds that... but haven't found it. Also, unsure is that good practice

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

# Define the directory path to check
cfg_directory = "cfg"

# Check if the directory exists
if os.path.exists(cfg_directory):
    print(f"The '{cfg_directory}' directory exists in your project.")

    # Check for specific configuration files (e.g., YAML and JSON)
    config_files = ["config.yaml", "config.json"]
    for config_file in config_files:
        file_path = os.path.join(cfg_directory, config_file)
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            print(f"The '{config_file}' file exists in the '{cfg_directory}' directory.")
        else:
            print(f"The '{config_file}' file does not exist in the '{cfg_directory}' directory.")
else:
    print(f"The '{cfg_directory}' directory does not exist in your project.")
```

You can use this simple code

Comment: I think that will work if this file is directly in the project main directory only